# Save associated resources when save in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

An article and an associated tag are related `many to many`.
How can I sync tags to article in a transaction when creating a new article?

**Article.php**

```
class Article extends Model {

  protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];

  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'article_tags');
  }

}
```

**ArticlesController.php**

```
public function store(StoreArticleRequest $request)
{
  if ($request->has('article.tags_attributes.value')) {
    $tags_value = $request->input('article.tags_attributes.value');
    $splited_tags_value = explode(',', $tags_value);

    if (count($splited_tags_value) > 0) {
      $tags = [];
      foreach(@$splited_tags_value as $tag_value) {
        $tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['value' => trim($tag_value)]);
      }
    }
  }

  $article = new Article($request->input('article'));
  if ($article->save()->tags()->sync($tags)) {
    return redirect('console/articles')->with('success', '...');
  } else {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do database transaction as something like this.

```
public function store(StoreArticleRequest $request)
{
  if ($request->has('article.tags_attributes.value')) {
    $tags_value = $request->input('article.tags_attributes.value');
    $splited_tags_value = explode(',', $tags_value);

    if (count($splited_tags_value) > 0) {
      $tags = [];
      foreach(@$splited_tags_value as $tag_value) {
        $tags[] = Tag::firstOrCreate(['value' => trim($tag_value)]);
      }
    }
  }

  DB::transaction(function() {
    $article = new Article($request->input('article'));
    $article->save();
    $syncResult=$article->tags()->sync($tags);
  });

  if ($syncResult) {
    return redirect('console/articles')->with('success', '...');
  } else {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
}
```

Comment: any other method without specify a transaction?

Comment: afaik this is the only method to quarantee that all the database updates will fail or be rolled back. Why is this method not OK for you?